# How to change section titles inside a file so they follow a numeric pattern

Tags: python, bash

I have this .ini file which have several sections inside it, all of these sections have a title that follows this format: **[ StartN ]** where N is an integer in a number sequence that starts with 1.Example:

```
[Start1]
    LIST
    OF
    PARAMETERS
[Start2]
    LIST
    OF
    PARAMETERS

    ...
    ...

[Start347]
    LIST
    OF
    PARAMETERS
```

I need to edit this file and delete some of the above mentioned sections, but after that, I need the titles of each section to be renamed so they follow the numeric sequence. The same needs to be done but with files with about 500+ sections which may take too much time to do manually.

I tried to automate this by using a FOR loop in bash with GREP but had no success. I have no experience using bash and it is needed to be done using it. Python is also an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

design thought: doing this with bash scripting is going to be hard enough that you may as well shift that complexity into python.  The trick is keeping a running counter of your section numbers, and that will be hard to do in any bash tool.

Something like this might get you started. Trying to think of how to do this in the most simple way possible.
Regular expressions might help with code golfing this to fewer lines but I don't think it would help the readability.

Design-wise, I can't think of a reason to keep the original [Start] lines around, we'll just renumber all of them from 1+ and keep going to the end of file.
edit: I think it is a useful safety net to do things like the assert just to make sure we aren't matching on something unexpected.

I would say to add print statements as needed to see what the different values are doing.

To run, try:

```
$ python section_renum.py > newfile.dat
```

code for section_renum.py:

```
# assuming python2
def checkSection(line):
    if not line.startswith('[ Start'):
        return False
    if not line.endswith(']'):
        return False
    x = line[7:-1] # extract 999 from "[start999]"
    # In other langs this might be something like:
    #    n = line.substr(6, len(line)-1))
    x = x.strip()
    assert x.isdigit()
    return True

section_cnt = 0
line_cnt = 0
with open('foo.dat', 'r') as f:
    line_cnt += 1
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if checkSection(line):
            section_cnt += 1
            print '[ Start%d ]' % section_cnt
        else:
            print line
```